# deleting / resetting DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a web application in which you view/explore a 2D network graph.
when you mouseover a node, a request is sent to the server - the server gathers information and sends it back to the client - the client saves all informations in a JS class TooltipGraphListener like this:

```
var w = new scripts.widget.GraphInfo({ 
    baseURL: this._baseURL, 
    basePath: 'graphs/' + this._graphName, 
    path: 'nodes/' + nid, 
    tooltip: true });

var domNode = w.domNode;
dojo.removeClass(domNode, 'graphInfo');
domNode.setAttribute("id", nid);
this._canvas.containerNode.appendChild(domNode);
dojo.addClass(domNode, 'tooltip');
dojo.style(domNode,  "opacity", 0.8);
this._toolTips.push(w);
```

my problem now is that if I generate a new graph in the web app's widget this line:

```
var tooltip = dojo.byId(id);
if (tooltip)...
```

still is true, even if I clear _toolTips (_toolTips = []) or re-initialize the whole class (listener = new TooltipGraphListener()).. the individual tooltips can still be found by dojo.byId(id);

how can I reset/delete all these tooltip domnodes?

Comment: I just now remarked the line this._canvas.containerNode.appendChild(domNode);
I guess that's where the problem lies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clear your tooltips, you'll also have to remove their DOM nodes from the document (I'm sure there's a more dojo way of doing this, but I haven't used that framework):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this._tooltips.length; i++) {
    this._canvas.containerNode.removeChild(this._tooltips[i].domNode);
}
this._tooltips = [];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! now it is kind of obvious that _canvas was keeping the domnodes alive - I dont know why I did not see it before..

Comment: You can use `dojo.destroy` for this - pass it the DOM node to be destroyed.  It has some special considerations for avoiding memory leaks in old versions of IE.  If these tooltips are actually Dijit widgets, they have their own destruction methods, the most commonly-used of which is `destroyRecursive` (which ensures that any child widgets are also destroyed).

Comment: @KenFranqueiro thanks, `dojo.destroy`works nicely. I cannot use `destroyRecursive` since the tooltips that I'm using are not dojo tooltips (they would not work on the 3rd party widget that I'm using).

Answer (score 1):

The GraphInfo class must be appending the tooltip element to the DOM. You have to remove it, or it will always be there, regardless of what happens to your class. The 'byId' method is looking in the DOM for an element with that ID.

If you really must be able to reset the thing you'll have to build a dispose() method into the class, in which it would remove the DOM elements that it added. That or you can just reuse the same DOM element for each instance, assuming it's ok that there can only be 1 showing on the page at a time (since it is a tooltip, I think that is the case).

Comment: ok, so I guess it will be the dispose() method, since I want to reduce server calls. If I create a new tooltip with each mouseover the server would be called unnecessarily often. this should do the trick, right? `var node = this._canvas.containerNode while (node.hasChildNodes()) { 
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}`